# append multi-level json array into html table javascipt

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, json

I have url json data multi-level array which append it into html tabe, how i can append into html table the fird level of array?
My code only works with first&second level data

id:457 - first level,
ids: 460, 458 - second levels,
id: 743 - third level
How i can append array with id 743 into my html table?
I just try use **for** but its not works

```js
data = [
   {
      "id": 457,
      "name": "name1",
      "code": "url1",
      "show_code": "url1",
      "icon": null,
      "image": null,
      "productsCount": 1,
      "items": [
         {
            "id": 460,
            "name": "name2",
            "code": "url2",
            "show_code": "url2",
            "icon": null,
            "image": null,
            "productsCount": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 458,
            "name": "name3",
            "code": "url3",
            "show_code": "url3",
            "icon": null,
            "image": null,
            "productsCount": 1,
            "items": [
               {
                  "id": 743,
                  "name": "name4",
                  "code": "url4",
                  "show_code": "url4",
                  "icon": null,
                  "image": null,
                  "productsCount": 1
               }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
]
           
$(document).ready(function(){

    var product_data = '';
$.each(data, function (i, data) {
    $.each(data.items, function (i, items) {
        $.each(items.items, function (i, item) { 
        product_data += '<tr>';
            product_data += '<td class="nav-submenu css-n9ebcy-Item">  <a class="code-parent" target="_blank" href="test' + data.code + '">' + data.name + '(' + data.id + ')' + '</a></td>';     
            product_data += '<td class="child-item"><a class="code-child" target="_blank" href="test' +
                      items.code + '/' + items.show_code + '">' + items.name + ' ' + '(' + items
                      .productsCount  +
                      ')' + '</a></td>';                     
                      for(var i=0; i<items.items.length;i++){
                        product_data += '<td>' + items.items[i].name + '</td>';
                        }
            
                    //   product_data += '<td class="child-item"><a class="code-child" target="_blank" href="https://test' +
                    //   items.items.code + '</a></td>';
                      product_data += '</tr>';
});
});    
});    
   
$('#showData').append(product_data);

});
```

```css
th, td, p, input {
            font:14px Verdana;
        }
        table, th, td 
        {
            border: solid 1px #DDD;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 2px 3px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        th {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="showData" class="tavle">
<tr>

    <th>level 1</th>
    <th>level 2</th>
    <th>level 3</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi Dmitiry - please fix the syntax errors in the provided code.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, sorry, now its correct

Comment: `items.items` in the third loop rather than `data.items.items`

Comment: @RandyCasburn its works, but now show only one catogery on all levels

Comment: @RandyCasburn, i understand, thanks for help:)